# How to check that a stored procedure with no return value has been executed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am executing a stored procedure that has no return value. How can I check that it has actually been executed? Here is the code:

```
this.dbProviderFactory = DalFactory.GetFactory(this.adapterConfiguration);
DbConnection dbConnection = dbProviderFactory.CreateConnection();

dbConnection.ConnectionString = this.adapterConfiguration.DatabaseInformation.ExternalDatabaseInformation.connectionString;
dbConnection.Open();

DbCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "h_AS_SP_ResetUnfinishedJobs";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[h_AS_SP_ResetUnfinishedJobs]
AS
BEGIN
 -- Delete all unfinished jobs where the force flag has not been set...
 DELETE FROM h_AS_mds_MetaDataStatus
 WHERE mds_status NOT IN (11,12) AND mds_force = 0
END
```

Comment: What language are you using? What database? Why are you not sure your code executed the stored procedure?

Comment: I am inexperinced in everything involving databases. It's a MySQL-database. I just want to somehow check that the stored procedure was actually executed.

Comment: And what _language_ are you using? Why do you need to check? If you called it and there was no exception, it was called.

Comment: C#. And yes, it was called. I looked at the stored procedure and changed a value in a row in the database. The row was subsequently deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stored proc will return a "number of rows affected" when using `ExecuteNonQuery()`:

```
DbCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "h_AS_SP_ResetUnfinishedJobs";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will give you an idea whether or not anything has even been done. However: if not affecting any rows also is a valid outcome for your stored proc, you cannot really use that return value to check if it's been run.

Other than that: unless an exception occurs, the call presumably worked !